# How to make that one block scrolls and the second block remained in place?

Tags: css

There are two blocks of the same height and width. It is necessary that initially the first one be superimposed on the second one. When scrolling, the first one should scroll and open the second block (the second one should remain in place. The first one opens like a curtain). How to implement this or what properties should be used?

```
.parent {
    &__first {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      background: lightblue;
    }
    &__second {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      background: gray;
    }
  }
```

UPD:
example: https://s-sd.ru/files/revealing-hero-effect/main/index.html
So can I get this behaviour without opacity change and only by css?

Comment: can you add some more details or screenshot for more clarity?

Comment: I have two blocks with same height and width. Initially first block placed at the second. While scrolling, first block should scroll and "open" second block.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: This is not standard CSS. You need to tag whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

for making a curtain effect with two boxes you can follow this approach. Here, animation is applied to the light-blue color box and its going upwards showing the gray color box.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    animation: curtain 2000ms ease-out forwards; /* Specify duration and timing function */
}

.curtain-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: gray;
}

@keyframes curtain {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }

    100% {
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Curtain Effect</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="curtain-container">
      <div class="curtain-top"></div>
      <div class="curtain-bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>` and all HTML tags.

Comment: I need get this behaviour by scroll, not by animation